# MicroUSB to MCU interface with logical level conversion

Tags: usb, schematics, voltage-divider, msp430, logic-level

I'm trying to interface a micro USB port to a microcontroller but I'm not sure about something.
The micro USB port will be connected to a computer with a simple USB cable and that will give me a 5V power supply, but the microcontroller its working at 3.3V. My question is the following: Do I need to add some dividers to adjust the level from the data pins (D+ and D-) or I can connect them directly to the microcontroller? If I need the divider, can you help me with a diagram on how to connect them?
Thank you[image]

Comment: USB signalling is not 5v.  If you are going to make a first attempt at USB, start with an already proven design.

Comment: What do you plan to achieve by connecting the USB D+ & D- signal lines to the P1.3 & P1.4 pins on your micro? As far as I can tell, that micro does not have a USB port. Are you planning to bit-bang as a low-speed HID device? Why do you have 15k pulldowns on both lines? That's supposed to be on the host/hub side!

Comment: my target is to control a step motor via USB..I thought it this way: I'm sending data from a PC through a USB cable to the USB port, the data goes through pins D- and D+ to the MCU and the MCU sends data to the motor

Comment: Ok - so that's your overall goal. You haven't addressed anything else in my comment ...

Comment: I need to send data from the USB port to the MCU , thats what I tried to do by conencted D- and D+ to the MCU pins...I dont know what do you mean by "bit-bang" and the 15k pulldowns resistors are there because I saw them on a schematic on how to use the micro-usb

Comment: I know its not very clear, to be honest I'm not very sure how to make the schematic..All I have is the project title : "Controlling step motor with USB" and I have to use the MSP430 microcontroller

Comment: Your chosen micro does not have a USB port. How to you intend to interpret the USB signaling coming from your PC? How do you intent to generate the necessary USB signaling back to your PC? Do you know what 'enumeration' means in the context of USB? Do you know what USB descriptors are? It looks to me as though you're in way over your head here ...

Comment: You're probably right with the last sentence:) Im not famliard with the USB descriptors or enumeration...I'll document myself better before starting..Thanks for the reply and patience:)

Comment: Are you using a launchpad? Because those pins look like the standard tx/rx serial pins for a msp430 on a launchpad. If so the usb to serial connection is already done.

Comment: Im not allowed to use a launchpad, but pin no2 and 3 from the MCU are tx and rx... Can i connect the D+ and D- to them?

Comment: UART and USB are entirely different. You need a microcontroller with USB support (such as the MSP430F5529), and the best way to learn about this is with the LaunchPad. Why are you doing a project about something you know nothing about? How are you supposed to learn?

Comment: Its for school...I only need to come up with an electrical schematic and a layout, no code.. And it supposed to be my own board, no launchpad allowed